# Store integers in a dataframe column wirhin a list

Tags: python, list, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a column of integer values but I can't seem to figure out how to put those values within the column into a list. Working with a dataset of 28000 rows.. shortened example is below. Column is of type object. The integers also don't have spaces after the commas (not sure if this detail is of any importance to the solution) but also how do I ensure there is a space after every comma since i plan to check the length of each list afterwards.

So for example,

```
NUMBERS ------> NUMBERS
 1,2,3                [1,2,3]
 2,3,4                [2,3,4]
 3,7,7                [3,7,7]
 4                    [4]
 5                    [5]
 6                    NaN
 7                    [7]
 8                    NaN
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why are 6 and 8 mapping to NaN?

Comment: `df.NUMBERS.str.split(',')`

Comment: 6 and 8 are mapping to nan because in the dataset there are empty rows in the column. I'm performing an analysis and can't just put in my own values

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you have certain values mapping to `nan`, but you could use:

```
In [164]: df['NUMBERS'].apply(lambda x: x.split(','))
Out[164]:
0    [1, 2, 3]
1    [2, 3, 4]
2    [3, 7, 7]
3          [4]
4          [5]
5          [6]
6          [7]
7          [8]
Name: NUMBERS, dtype: object
```

Comment: 6 and 8 are mapping to nan because in the dataset there are empty rows in the column. I'm performing an analysis and can't just put in my own values